# Handling toggle of divs upon a click event using Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two `divs` in my html page, side by side.

I want to click a `button` and have the `div` on the right toggle (show/hide) . So I use jquery and jquery's .toggle() method.

The problem is that when I toggle the right div the div on the left seems to move left and go half way off the screen. I went through the dev tools in Chrome and I think that it is bootstrap that is messing with my divs

So I think that I will have to write my own `css` to override the bootstrap css but I'm not sure

Link to the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lhalverson/benvosLn/) that shows my problem.

Once the right div is hidden I would like the left div to then fill the screen. (Width wise)

**FIX**

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lhalverson/benvosLn/1/)

Comment: That's because Bootstrap has a system that adds up to 12, when you remove 2 of those and end up with 10, the system no longer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `push-md-10` try instead using the regular `col-md-12` as your restructuring

so if you want the divs to stay in place on the page you can have

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
    //Content to hide
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
   //content to hide
 </div>
```

Now you can just hide the stuff in that column

***Another example:***

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-5"> something worth 5 pushed 3 over </div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

NOTE: you always want a factor of `12` because that constitutes a bootstrap row size

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks Jay! I am going to look into the push/pull part of bootstrap now that I understand it a little more.